# How to pass JWT token after login using alamofire in iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, authentication, jwt, alamofire

I implemented login based on this [Networking sample](https://github.com/AladinWay/NetworkingExample), and its working fine and I got a response value too. These things are done inside the framework.

In framework I have implemented login api call and in sample app, I will be calling apicall.login method. After getting successful response it will return to framework with response.

From framework how can I get the authToken value from the returned response?

Here is code written for framework: APIRouter.swift

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

enum APIRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

case login(username:String, password:String)
case getFilter


// MARK: - HTTPMethod
private var method: HTTPMethod {
    switch self {
    case .login:
        return .post
    case .getFilter:
        return .get
    }
}

// MARK: - Path
private var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .login:
        return "/authentication"
    case .getFilter:
        return "/filter"
    }
}

// MARK: - Parameters
private var parameters: Parameters? {
    switch self {
    case .login(let username, let password):
        return [K.APIParameterKey.username: username, K.APIParameterKey.password: password]

    case .getFilter:

        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: - URLRequestConvertible
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try K.ProductionServer.baseURL.asURL()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
    print(urlRequest)
    // HTTP Method
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    let token: String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Token") ?? ""
    let bearerToken: String = "Bearer " + token
    print("baearer token::\(bearerToken)")

    // Common Headers
    urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.acceptType.rawValue)
    urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)
    urlRequest.setValue(bearerToken, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.authentication.rawValue)

    // Parameters
    if let parameters = parameters {
        do {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }
    }

    return urlRequest
   }
}
```

here is the code for APIClient.swift:

```
    import Foundation
 import Alamofire

 public class APIClient {
 @discardableResult
private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter, decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(), completion:@escaping (AFResult<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {

    return AF.request(route)
                    .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
                        completion(response.result)
                        print(response.result)

    }


 }


public static func login(username: String, password: String, completion:@escaping (AFResult<User>)->Void) {
    performRequest(route: APIRouter.login(username: username, password: password), completion: completion)
}

  public static func getFilter(completion:@escaping (AFResult<[Filter]>)->Void) {
       let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    performRequest(route: APIRouter.getFilter, decoder: jsonDecoder, completion: completion)
   }


  }//APIClient
```

Here is the Framework return response value:

```
    framework response:: success(Flow.User(username: "demo", authToken: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhOGZsb3ciLCJleHAiOjE1NzM4ODQ1OTgsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZGVtbyJ9.funhPTuI6WjWOo0M2mKS_tDr0QBUkQ8SnDqdSKhrWog", expireDate: "Sat Nov 16 06:09:58 UTC 2019"))
```

Apicall method inside sample app:

```
      APIClient.login(username: "demo", password: "demo") { (result) in
        switch result {
                   case .success(let login):
                       print("_____________________________")
                       print(login)



                   case .failure(let error):
                       print(error.localizedDescription)
                   }
    }
```

How can I pass the JWT token to the header field using alamofire?

Comment: so you got an access token (which is a JSON Web Token (JWT)) and want to know how to add it to the request header, right?

Comment: @jps yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

`allHeaderFields` contains this information

```
public typealias AFDataResponse<Success> = DataResponse<Success, AFError>

public struct DataResponse<Success, Failure: Error> {

    /// The server's response to the URL request.
    public let response: HTTPURLResponse?

}

open class HTTPURLResponse : URLResponse {
open var allHeaderFields: [AnyHashable : Any] { get }
}
```

So, to obtain, you should code like this:

ret

```
urn AF.request(route)
                    .responseDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in

                        print(response.response.allHeaderFields)

    }
```

Comment: @ParameswaranV it depends on your architecture. I've written an example of how you can obtain it.

Comment: @ParameswaranV so, accept the answer if it was helpful